# Trying to move a MSVC2008 project to MSVC2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to move [this project](https://github.com/svkaiser/PowerslaveEX) form VisualStudio 2008 to VisualStudio 2017. This project is a C++ project and when I try to compile it there are a lot of errors:

[image]

Errors are:

- the source file can not be opened (E1696).
- the global scope does not have... (E0282).
- the identifier ... is not defined (E0020).

The solution file of the project is in the folder kex3_anubis/msvc/

The project is open source.

**# EDIT**

I have lowered the number of errors to 17, but there are 126 warnings. What I have done is to select **Project -> redirect projects** (2nd option of project menu) and select Windows SDK version to 10.0.15063.0. I don't know if this is a good step or is not part of the solution, because it's the first time that I'm trying to move a project from different versions of VS.

[image]

The new errors are:

- The declaration of ... hides the previous local statement (C4456)
- Warning treated as error; no generated 'object' file (C2220)

The other errors have disappeared.

**# EDIT 2**

For the moment I applied this solution found on other question:

> Go to project properties -> configurations properties -> C/C++ ->
>   treats warning as error -> No (/WX-).

Now I only have one error.

> can not open the file '...\openal\lib\ eaxguid.lib' from anubis project

Comment: Those are all Intellisense errors. You can select to show compiler errors only, until you have sorted out the worst part of those.

Comment: If you switched compilers as well, make sure that you have installed the windows 10 SDK, that's what contains the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
#include "math.h"
```

use

```
#include <math.h>
```

In all the standard includes

Comment: Seems the author uses `#include <math.h>`